# To form a pie chart of a pie chart with different data in excel

Tags: excel, charts, pie-chart

I have an excel with 2 rows, Fruits and Vegetables.

```
-----------------------------
Fruits         |  100
-----------------------------
Vegetables     |  50
---------------------------
```

Also I have another section which is  a subset of fruits.

```
-----------------------------
Fruits I like         |  30
-----------------------------
Fruits I don't like   |  70
---------------------------
```

How do I create a pie chart of a pie chart where the first pie chart is fruits and vegetables and second is a pie chart which is extended from the fruits section and divided into fruits I like and fruits I don't like?

I know how to get the first pie chart but the second one does not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using excel 2010 but the options should be similar or the same in later versions.

You'll have to change your data arrangement a little and put everything altogether into one series, like this:

```
Vegetables           | 50
Fruits I like        | 30
Fruits I don't like  | 70
```

The you can insert a "Pie of Pie" chart. When you "Format the data series" chose:

- "Split Series by Position"
- Set "Second plot contains the last" 2 values

[image]

You can find more details here:

[Creating Pie of Pie Chart](https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2010/tips/creating_pie_of_pie_and_bar_of_pie_charts.html)